# XSLT: Remove Extra NameSpaces from xsl's output

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, bpel

Need Suggestion : 
 I have a XML file having default namespace(xmlns ="http://apr") which need to be removed, while keeping the rest of namespaces

```
 <p:Value xmlns:p="http://www.test.be/communication/xml/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test/communication/xml/v2 sample.xsd ">
    <Data xmlns ="http://apr"> Extra name space add using xslt need to remove this
    <Name>Apple</Name>
    </Data>
    </p:Value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
<xsl:template match="p:Value"  xmlns:p="http://www.test.be/communication/xml/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test/communication/xml/v2 sample.xsd ">
<p:Value xmlns:p="http://www.test.be/communication/xml/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.test/communication/xml/v2 sample.xsd ">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
</p:Value>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" >
     <xsl:element name="{name()}" >
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above code, the first xsl:template match="p:Value" will be invoked as soon as it gets the element  Then it will push the  element with respective name spaces as mentioned in that template. 
Later it is calling apply-templates so it will be redirect to next template with match="*"
In that template we are not adding namespace element  so it will remove the namespace for all other elements.

Regards,
Vikrant Korde.

Answer (score 1):

Some points:

1. in XSLT always remember that the name of an element is a (namespace,
   localname) pair.
2. if you get the name of an element (in the result tree) right, then
   the namespace declarations will take care of themselves
3. you need to change the names of elements in the http://apr namespace
   from ("http://apr", *) to ("", *)
4. to achieve this you need the template rule:

`<xsl:template match="apr:*" xmlns:apr="http://apr">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>`

Comment: Hi Michael Thanks for reply i tried your logic but getting result :             
    <Data> 
    <Name>Apple</Name>
    </Data>              it removing all namespace which i don't want.